# Display dynamic content in footer rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my footer, which is located in a partial _footer under layouts, I want to display the last 3 articles written on my app. I am getting the error `Undefined method each for nilClass for @articles` which I have sent up in the

ArticlesController index as

```
    @articles=Article.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
```

Where should I define @articles to have access to it in my whole app? I have tried to put it into application controller but was still getting an error.

In my _footer.html.erb which in in Application layouts

```
       <div class="col-md-3 md-margin-bottom-40">
      <div class="posts">
        <div class="headline"><h2>Latest Posts</h2></div>
         <% @articles.each do |article| %>
        <ul class="list-unstyled latest-list">
           <li>
            <a href="#"><%= article.title.titleize %></a>
            <small><%= article.created_at.strftime("%B-%m-%Y") %></small>
        </ul>
      <% end %>
      </div>
    </div><!--/col-md-3-->
```

_footer partial is being called here:

```
    <body>
<div class="wrapper">
 <%= render "layouts/header" %>

 <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
 <%= yield %>
 <div class="container">
 </div>
 <%= render "layouts/footer"%>
```

Comment: That looks like a different question to me

Comment: I understood the problem to be accessing a variable defined in the controller from the layout. After your answer I realized it was a partial issue, not a layout one.

Comment: can you post where you are calling the partial, like index.html.erb of the articlescontroller?

Comment: refer to my answer, use <%= render 'layouts/footer', obj: @articles %> instead, and in the footer partial, use obj.each instead

Comment: obj is coming up as nil

Comment: I think the problem has to be something with @articles being defined in the ArticlesController

Comment: Are you sure there is anything in Article? do rails c and then Article.count and see if its not 0.

Comment: I have 75 articles in the db

Comment: do you see anything in @articles in the controller?

Comment: I don't understand the question. In index i have defined @articles as I stated above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you want to display `@articles` in every page you're gonna have to assign it every time. To do so, add the following to your `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_action :load_articles

private

  def load_articles
    @articles = Article.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
  end

end
```

Then `@articles` will be available in every page so your footer will work.

You can remove the assignation of `@articles` from your `ArticlesController` as it's already assigned by the `ApplicationController`. Be careful not to assign something else to `@articles` though.

Comment: you're the man. Thank You!! This makes a lot of sense as well, I was close to this but not quite a few minutes ago

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html.erb, you should render the partial and pass in @articles like so

```
<%= render 'layouts/footer', obj: @articles %>
```

In your footer partial, refer to @articles as obj. You can change obj to any name you want.

Comment: The problem is @articles.each do |article| is giving me a nil for articles

Comment: where are you calling @articles.each?

Comment: to display Article title and created_at

Comment: i mean are you calling it in the footer partial or index.html.erb

Comment: ohh in footer partial

Comment: like i said in my answer, replace @articles with obj, so obj.each do { whatever }

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to show @articles in your websites footer you probably need set @articles for all controllers, not just ArticlesController, try setting @articles in ApplicationController:

```
before_filter :set_articles

private
  def set_articles
    @articles = Article.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
  end
```

Second step:

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <%= render "layouts/header" %>

  <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
  <%= yield %>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  <%= render "layouts/footer", locals: {articles: @articles} %>
</body>
```

and inside your footer partial use article instead of @articles

```
<div class="col-md-3 md-margin-bottom-40">
  <div class="posts">
    <div class="headline"><h2>Latest Posts</h2></div>
     <% articles.each do |article| %>
       <ul class="list-unstyled latest-list">
         <li>
          <a href="#"><%= article.title.titleize %></a>
          <small><%= article.created_at.strftime("%B-%m-%Y") %></small>
       </ul>
     <% end %>
  </div>
</div><!--/col-md-3-->
```

More on partials:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: this its not a problem of partials. Can you display how to set it up in App controller I tried defining a method there and placing  @articles=Article.order("created_at DESC").limit(3) there but still no success